# MySQL Integer column, unique values but default possibility?

Tags: mysql, integer, default, unique

I want a table with an integer column, that may or may not be filled (it is a social security number). But if it is filled, I want it to be UNIQUE : there cannot be two entries of the same number.

Using a unique constraint won't work cause integer won't accept NULL values, and MySQL detects multiple 0 values.

How can I set a unique constraint on an integer with a default value ? Or how can I set the integer column to accept NULL values ? (this question takes it for granted : [MySQL Foreign Key Constraint - Integer Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046723/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-integer-column) but I can't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table test (
    myint INT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX (myint)
);
```

This will allow a unique constraint on any integers added but will allow multiple NULL values to be entered.

MySQL treats NULL as 'unknown' value so cant possibly do a comparison to see if a like value is already there 'unknown' !== 'unknown'.

This also depends on which database engine you are using, the above holds true for MyISAM and InnoDB

Comment: using InnoDB. How can I do it when the table is ALREADY there ? seems like I can't alter it this way :/

Comment: well you should be able to issue a alter statement

ALTER TABLE test MODIFY myint INT NULL;
ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE INDEX (myint);

Answer (score 2):

Please see the code below:

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY myint INT NULL
ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE INDEX (myint)
```

It works when data inputs are directly from MySQL (PHPMyadmin), saved as NULL, but a php script saves it as zeroes, and so it does not allow multiple entries.